# Blazor how to create dynamic form

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to create a dynamic form in Blazor but I'm stuck. I have a  FormFactory component that takes two input parameters. Model for my data binding and a dictionary that defines which elements should be created.
The idea is to pass a model object

```
public class Data 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

and a dictionary

```
{ "Name": "string" },
{ "Phone": "string" }
```

I want to create a form with two input fields for Name and Phone bound to the properties in my model.

```
<h3>Dynamic form</h3>
<EditForm Model="@DataContext">
    @foreach (var field in FieldIdentifiers)
    {
        if (field.Value == "string")
        {
            <InputText @bind-Value="DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(DataContext, null).ToString()"></InputText>
        }
    }    
</EditForm>    
@code {    
    [Parameter] public object DataContext { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, string> FieldIdentifiers { get; set; }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I get an error saying

> "Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because
>   some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
>   to the delegate return type" and "The left hnad side of an assignment
>   must be a variable, property or indexer"

EDIT:
I've found that Blazor generates a ValueChanged attribute that causes error

```
builder2.AddAttribute(8, "ValueChanged", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.String>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<System.String>(this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateInferred(this, __value => DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(DataContext, null).ToString() = __value, DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(DataContext, null).ToString()))));
```

That won't work so I tried creating a RenderFragment and changed my component as following

```
<h3>Dynamic form</h3>
@MyForm()


@code {

    [Parameter] public object DataContext { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, string> FieldIdentifiers { get; set; }

    RenderFragment MyForm() => builder =>
    {
        builder.AddMarkupContent(0, "<h3>Dynamic form</h3>\r\n");
        builder.OpenComponent<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm>(1);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "Model", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.Object>(DataContext));
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "ChildContent", (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext>)((context) => builder2 =>
        {
            builder2.AddMarkupContent(4, "\r\n");
            foreach (var field in FieldIdentifiers)
            {
                if (field.Value == "string")
                {
                    builder2.AddContent(5, "            ");
                    builder2.OpenComponent<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputText>(6);
                    builder2.AddAttribute(7, "Value", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.String>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.BindMethods.GetValue(DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(DataContext, null).ToString())));
                    builder2.AddAttribute(8, "ValueChanged", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.String>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<System.String>(this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateInferred(this, __value => DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).SetValue(DataContext, __value), DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(DataContext, null).ToString()))));
                    builder2.AddAttribute(9, "ValueExpression", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<System.String>>>(() => Convert.ToString(DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(DataContext, null))));
                    builder2.CloseComponent();
                    builder2.AddMarkupContent(10, "\r\n");
                }
            }

            builder2.AddMarkupContent(11, "\r\n");
        }));
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

This compiles but I get a runtime error

> System.ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a 
>   MethodCallExpression1 which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports > simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/u2ee6kjb) for working sample.

Your problem was with `ValueExpression`, that required it to be an expression to get a property (or similar).
I create this in my sample:

```
var constant = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(DataContext, typeof(DataX));
var exp = System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Property(constant, fld);
var lamb = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(exp);
builder.AddAttribute(4, "ValueExpression", lamb);
```

For `Value` and `ValueChanged` I use reflection to get and set the property values.

```
// Get the initial property value
var propInfoValue = typeof(DataX).GetProperty(fld);
var s = propInfoValue.GetValue(DataContext);
builder.AddAttribute(1, "Value", s);

// Create the handler for ValueChanged. I use reflection to the value.
builder.AddAttribute(3, "ValueChanged", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.String>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<System.String>(this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateInferred(this, __value => propInfoValue.SetValue(DataContext, __value), (string)propInfoValue.GetValue(DataContext)))));
```

I'm quite new working with Linq's `Expression` classes so there may be better ways to do this.
Also the code for `ValueChanged` is based on the generated code for a static InputText. There may be better ways for this as well.

Full code:
**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"

<h3>Dynamic form</h3>
<EditForm Model="@DataContext">
    @foreach (var field in FieldIdentifiers)
    {
        if (field.Value == "string")
        {
            @field.Key
            @CreateComponent(field.Key);
            <br />
        }
    }

    <h3>Statically declared</h3>
    <InputText @bind-Value="@DataContext.Name"></InputText> <br>
    Name: @DataContext.Name
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter] public DataX DataContext { get; set; } = new DataX();
    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, string> FieldIdentifiers { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Name", "string" }, { "Phone", "string" } };

    public RenderFragment CreateComponent(string fld) => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(InputText));

        // Get the initial property value
        var propInfoValue = typeof(DataX).GetProperty(fld);
        var s = propInfoValue.GetValue(DataContext);
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "Value", s);

        // Create the handler for ValueChanged. I use reflection to the value.
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "ValueChanged", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.String>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<System.String>(this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateInferred(this, __value => propInfoValue.SetValue(DataContext, __value), (string)propInfoValue.GetValue(DataContext)))));

        // Create an expression to set the ValueExpression-attribute.
        var constant = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(DataContext, typeof(DataX));
        var exp = System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Property(constant, fld);
        var lamb = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(exp);
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "ValueExpression", lamb);

        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

**DataX.cs**

```
public class DataX
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Jane Doe";
    public string Phone { get; set; } = "123456789";
    public string Address { get; set; } = "The Street";
}
```

**Edit**: I just saw that you had the "blazor-clientside" tag on the question. I have just tested this with server-side Blazor.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The ValueExpression property, which is usually set by the compiler, is needed here, to tell the compiler how to produce values... Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I've tested it on client side blazor and it works as expected. Thank you!!

Comment: The Fiddle environment was also updated. So the original source code doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 5):

Ran across this while researching, but I ended up just skipping `@bind-value` and using `value` and `onchanged` directly instead to set the properties via reflection:

```
    @foreach (var p in Datacontext.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        <input type="text" 
               placeholder="@p.Name" 
               value="@p.GetValue(Datacontext)"
               @onchange="(e) => p.SetValue(Datacontext, e.Value)">
    }
```

This code doesn't do any type conversion for the properties, its just to illustrate the use of a closure over the property object with the onchange handler

Perhaps someone will find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to iterate through the properties of the Model object (DataContext), and assign an expression whose evaluation should be in the form of "DataContext.Phone", for instance, to the @bind-Value directive

```
public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

    }

<h3>Dynamic form</h3>
<EditForm Model="@DataContext">
  for (int i = 0; i < DataContext.GetType().GetProperties().Count(); i++ )
{
    var name = "DataContext.";
    name += DataContext.GetType().GetProperties().ElementAt(i).Name;
   <InputText @bind-Value="@name"></InputText>
}

</EditForm>    
@code {    
    [Parameter] public Data DataContext { get; set; }

}
```

Hope this works...

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.. It has the same problem as my attempted solution.. Genrated Blazor code for ValueChanged looks like
 __value => "DataContext." +  DataContext.GetType().GetProperties().ElementAt(i).Name = __value
and that resultes in an error

Comment: OK, I understand...the expression is not evaluated to the required result. I've updated my answer. Let's hope that the alteration will work. If using "@name" does not work try "@(@name)"  Good luck

Comment: We are getting close.. This code compiles and runs but the initaial value of input is "DataContext.Text1".. I can delete that text and enter something else (like "No name") but when input loses focus the text I entered is deleted and value is reverted to "DataContext.Text1".. Variable name is evaluated to string "DataContext.Text1", not to the property of and object DataContext